# is it safe to have coaxial cables set up like this?

Tags: coax

Wondering if this set up poses any harm or anything [image]

Comment: I imagine it can be pretty bad if you trip over it and hit your nose against the table.

Comment: Haha yeah that would be the obvious concern

Answer (score 1):

It does not look pretty and, as pointed out in a comment, it could be a tripping harzard, but purely from the electrical point of view (not talking about the code), it should be ok.

The coax cable and coax connections are well shielded and, therefore, high frequency signals flowing in coax cables should not cause interference or be disturbed by a nearby AC lines.

Also, with the AC cable being well insulated and carrying relatively low voltage signal, there is no risk of accidental arcing or shorting to the exposed grounded coax connector.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the detailed response I appreciate that.